# How to: Use images in a project, if they come from an embedded assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uri, .net-assembly

**How to: Use images in a project, if they come from an embedded assembly**

I created an assembly which has a public method that uses images. These images are embedded. Now when I try using the assembly in my new project, everythings works fine except the images.

I tried to run the application without using an assembly (just a normal WPF application) and it worked. So it seems, that the assembly does not find the embedded images.

Could you please help me out?

**EDIT: The way I create the image used in my assembly.**

```
public void CreateBitmapImage(string uri)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute);
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        image_msgIcon.Source = bitmapImage;
    }

    public void SetMsgImage(string msgImage)
    {
        if (msgImage == Error)
        {
            CreateBitmapImage("pack://application:,,,/CL.New;component/Images/CustomMessageBox/cross-circle.png");
        }
        else if (msgImage == Exclamation)
        {
            CreateBitmapImage("pack://application:,,,/CL.New;component/Images/CustomMessageBox/exclamation.png");
        }
        else if (msgImage == Information)
        {
            CreateBitmapImage("pack://application:,,,/CL.New;component/Images/CustomMessageBox/information.png");
        }
        else if (msgImage == Question)
        {
            CreateBitmapImage("pack://application:,,,/CL.New;component/Images/CustomMessageBox/question.png");
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

**Now I get this error message:**

```
Die Ressource "images/custommessagebox/cross-circle.png" kann nicht gefunden werden.
The resource "images/custommessagebox/cross-circle.png" cannot be found.
```

**I tried it this way:**

```
CreateBitmapImage("/CL.New;component/Images/CustomMessageBox/cross-circle.png");
```

...

```
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative);
```

... this seems to work, but the image is not displayed (no error messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation.

Basically you should be using different `Uri`s when you're referencing resources from a different assembly.  As it states in the document, try using something like:

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Image.png
```

or

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/Image.png
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. Well I read the article, but I am not sure what is meant by "ReferencedAssembly" - is it the name of my dll, or is it the namespace's name? Using the dll's name, I get an error that the resource is not available.

Comment: If you build an assembly for a WPF Application named `SomeApplication`, then you get an assembly named `SomeApplication.exe`. Here, `ReferencedAssembly` means the name of the application rather than the complete name of the assembly file including the `exe` file extension.

Comment: @Exception to add to Sheridan, you want to replace `ReferencedAssembly` with the `Assembly name` of your project that is creating the resource assembly.  You can find the `Assembly name`, go to the project properties and you will see it under the Application tab.

Comment: Thanks, Sheridan and NETscape. It seems that there is no exe file. There is only the dll file. My `Class Library` is called "CL.New", so the only file in my debug folder is the "CL.New.dll". Please see my edited code.

Comment: @Exception you should be omitting the `.dll` extension: `pack://application:,,,/CL.New;component/Images/img_icon.png`

Comment: That is not working as well. Same error. I chose new Uri("pack...", UriKind.Absolute) as the UriSource - right way of coding?

Comment: @Exception At this point I'm guessing because I have no idea how its being used.  If you setup a small sample project that illustrates the issue I'll figure it out for you. You could .zip the project up and upload it somewhere or post the code on gist.github.com.

Comment: I have added my code, please see above. Thanks so far. ;)